# How to copy an array array of numbers using slice()

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I am trying to fill a game board (8 by 8) with random game pieces (images), but not the entire board is filled.  Some will be empty. To do so, I am randomly generating x,y coordinates on the board and assigning a random number to it.  Since fillBoard is private function in a module, I am copy it over to copyBoard, which is public function.

The idea is to randomly generate an x,y coordinate and put it in an array[x], array[y]. I am having trouble copying the array array though, since not all of them is defined.  I was wondering how do you do so?

Here's what I got so far. Its displaying an error because splice() cannot work for an undefined variable.

```
function fillBoard(){
    var x, y;
    monsters=[]; //empty array

    x = Math.floor(Math.random()*cols);
    y = Math.floor(Math.random()*rows);

    monsters[x] = []; /* making x variable an array */
    monsters[x][y] = Math.floor(Math.random() * numMonsterTypes);
}

function copyBoard() {
    var copy = [],
        x;

    for (x = 0; x < cols; x++) {
        if(monsters[x]){
            copy[x] = monsters[x].slice(0); //slice(array) -> returns the selected elements in an array
        };
    };
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: It really depends on the type of monsters you are storing.

Comment: Perhaps if you describe the actual problem you're trying to solve we might be able to better help with an appropriate solution.  Right now, what you're showing code for doesn't make a whole lot of sense so I think we need to know what you're really trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution:

```
function fillBoard(){
    var x, y;
    monsters=[]; //empty array

    x = Math.floor(Math.random()*cols);
    y = Math.floor(Math.random()*rows);

    monsters[x] = []; /* making x variable an array */
    monsters[x][y] = Math.floor(Math.random() * numMonsterTypes);
}

function copyBoard() {
    var copy = [],
        x;

    for (x = 0; x<cols; x++){
        copy[x] = [];
        if(monsters[x]){
            copy[x] = monsters[x].slice(0);;
        };
    };

    return copy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem arises from only random array element being initialised.
You can either iterate over all rows AND columns and copy initialise elements only
or
you can store a list/array of initilised elements somewhere else (array element maxRow+1/maxCol+1 ?)